# question regarding the *p and the p inside the for loop

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have two question about the following code, in particular the `int sum(const int *begin, const int *end)` function. The thing that I don't understand is why is it that we assign `p` as a pointer to an immutable constant i.e. begin. But then we also have `++p` in the `for` loop inside `sum()`? Why is it that it is `++p` but not `++*p`? And why is it that is is `p!=end` but not `*p!= end`?

I was reading that: "*In `const int *p`, `*p` (content pointed-to) is constant, but `p` is not constant.*"

I don't quite understand the difference between the usages of `*p` and `p` in this function.

My second question is: What is the reason of declaring `const` in:  `const int *p = begin` in the for loop of `int sum(...)`?  Is it because in the signature of `int sum(...)`, there is this `const` being declared for: `const int *p = begin`  ?  I.e. is it because `begin` is being declared as something that is immutable - so that's why in the for loop, we have to declare `begin` is an immutable constant pointed to by the pointer `*p`?

```
/* Function to compute the sum of a range of an array (SumArrayRange.cpp) */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
int sum(const int *begin, const int *end);

// Test Driver
   int main() {
   int a[] = {8, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8};
   cout << sum(a, a+8) << endl;        // a[0] to a[7]
   cout << sum(a+2, a+5) << endl;      // a[2] to a[4]
   cout << sum(&a[2], &a[5]) << endl;  // a[2] to a[4]
}

// Function definition
// Return the sum of the given array of the range from
// begin to end, exclude end.
int sum(const int *begin, const int *end) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (const int *p = begin; p != end; ++p) {
        sum += *p;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What source are you learning C++ from?

Comment: `p` is a pointer containing an address. `*p` is the value stored in that address. The pointer is declared by `int *p;`. `++p` increments the address. `++*p` increments the value.

Comment: As you already mentioned, `const int *p` would point to a const int, this mean that we can only move the pointer but not change the value that is pointing to. The function sum should only compute the sum in a given range and should not change the values of the array thus `const int*` is used to ensure this.

Comment: hello, but may I know what does it mean by increasing the address in this case?  because isn't address something like 0x321F ... or something like that? what does it mean by increasing the address by 1 here? like ++p? so 0x321F +1 ? and then +1 again?

Comment: If `p` is a pointer to element `i` in array `a`, then `p+1` is a pointer to `a[i+1]` (i.e. incrementing it makes it point to the next element).

Comment: *"we assign p as a pointer to an immutable constant i.e. begin"* - `p` is a mutable pointer to const-qualified `int` and it is initialized with value of another pointer of the same type, stored in variable `begin`

Comment: Adding to @melpomene answer, the elements of the array are stored sequentially in memory and that's why incrementing the pointer will point to the next element in the array.

Comment: The expression `++p` or `p + 1` adds `1 * sizeof(type)` to the *address* inside the pointer.  With an `int` pointer and the `sizeof(int) == 4`, then `4` will be added to the address in the pointer.  Best to think of incrementing as pointing to the next location in an array.

Comment: Hello, just another question. When we initiate a pointer, shouldn't it bec onst int *p = &begin ? i.e. the address of begin. But how comes it is initiated as const int *p = begin without the & sign?

Answer (score 0):

As a reminder, the table of `const` and pointers:

```
int * p -- Pointer to a mutable (read/write) location. Pointer and target data may be modified.
int const * p -- Pointer to read only location.  The data at the location constant, read-only.
int * const p -- Constant pointer to read/write location.  Pointer can't be changed, but data at location may be changed.  
int const * const p -- Constant pointer to constant data.  Neither pointer nor data may be changed.
```

In the declaration:

```
int sum(const int *begin, const int *end);
```

The pointers are mutable pointers to constant data.  The pointers may be modified, but they point to constant (read-only) data.

**Edit 1: Incrementing a pointer**
Let's assign a pointer, `p`, the value of 0x12.
Integers will be 4 bytes in length:

```
     +---+  
p -> | 1 | 0x12
     +---+  
     | 2 | 0x13
     +---+  
     | 3 | 0x14
     +---+  
     | 4 | 0x15
     +---+
     | 0 | 0x16
     +---+  
     | 6 | 0x17
     +---+  
     | 1 | 0x18
     +---+  
     | 9 | 0x19
     +---+
```

The integer at `*p` == 1234 (provided Big Endian layout).

Incrementing `p` will produce the address: `0x12 + 1 * sizeof(int)`, or
`0x12 + 1 * (4) == 0x16`.

```
          +---+  
p ->      | 1 | 0x12
          +---+  
          | 2 | 0x13
          +---+  
          | 3 | 0x14
          +---+  
          | 4 | 0x15
          +---+
p + 1 ->  | 0 | 0x16
          +---+  
          | 6 | 0x17
          +---+  
          | 1 | 0x18
          +---+  
          | 9 | 0x19
          +---+
```

**Edit 2: Alignment**
There is an issue of *alignment* at this perspective.
Let's assume the processor is 32-bits.  It has an internal register (word) size of 32 bits (4 octets).  The processor is defined to fetch 32-bits out of memory.

Let us store integers at addresses 4, 8, 12 and 16.  The binary representation of those addresses:

```
0000 0100 -- 4
0000 1000 -- 8
0000 1100 -- 12
0001 0000 -- 16
```

As you can see, the rightmost 2 bits are always zero.  The processor designer's don't need to implement the 2 rightmost address lines (thus saving money and real estate space).  In this processor, fetches at address evenly divisible by 4 are most efficient (1 fetch).  They are *aligned to a 4-byte boundary*.

Comment: hello, but may I know what does it mean by increasing the address in this case? because isn't address something like 0x321F ... or something like that? what does it mean by increasing the address by 1 here? like ++p? so 0x321F +1 ? and then +1 again?

Comment: p stores the address of something right?  so what does ++p do? I thought this increase the address by 1? so 0x321F + 1? but what does that equal to?

Comment: a memory address is just a number. hex is just the notation commonly used to express memory addresses. 0x321F + 1 would be 0x3220 i believe?